# Cannot create MobileAssistant- App Engine app for android using google cloud in Eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine

i tried https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/ for the development of android app using google cloud.I downloaded the necassary Google Plug-in in Eclipse.I am able to make the MobileAssitant App but when I generate "App Engine Backend",it says that MobileAssitant-App Engine can't be generated and shows errors instead.Please Help!

Errors are :-

1)Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater    DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /MobileAssistant-AppEngine/src/com/example/mobileassistant  line 60 Java Problem

2)Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater    MessageEndpoint.java    /MobileAssistant-AppEngine/src/com/example/mobileassistant  line 105    Java Problem

and there are 47 more errors.

Comment: Do you mind including more information to your case? saying "it shows errors" is one thing. Showing US the error is waaaaaaaay better